# Display table data

Tags: android

I have a List collection of my objects. I need to display this collection as a table:

> First column | Second | Button

TableLayout is not suitable because I need to receive chosen item.
I tried to extend BaseAdapter and return LinearLayout, which encapsulates row data.
But I receive exception:

> android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1779)

When I return TextView it work ok, but I need several view in a row.
Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cause of my problem. I set up `setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))` on returning LinearLayout. This caused exception setupChild. After deleting this, all works fine.